# How do I compare a string element to a unicode character in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, unicode, compare, character

I'm writing a code that will take in characters from the International Phonetic Alphabet and model them as phonemes to analyze phonologically. I need to be able to compare parts of a symbol (diacritics) to certain unicode characters. This is what I'm currently doing (what isn't working)

```
let diacritics : [String : String] = [
    ...
    "\u{2B0}" : "aspirated",
    ...
]

let elementsInSample = Array(sample)
for element in elementsInSample {
    if diacritics.keys.contains(String(element)) {
        \\Do things
    }
}
```

.contains will return false for ʰ when the key is in unicode. How do I rearrange the types so that it will be accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to work with Unicode Scalars, rather than Characters.

```
let diacritics : [Unicode.Scalar : String] = [
    //...
    "\u{2B0}" : "aspirated",
    //...
]

let sample = "ʰ"
for element in sample.unicodeScalars {
    if let value = diacritics[element] {
        print(value)
    }
}
```